# Save method of XDocument: into which directory will it be saved?

Tags: c#

I am using the lines below in the web service to see the XML which we send to another party:

```
XDocument doc;

doc.Save("san.xml");
```

In which directory can I find the `san.xml` file?

Comment: You'll find it under `your_project/bin/Debug/`.

Comment: normally, it will be the same folder from where your executable is started

Comment: @ Andrei V  ,  Thanadurai .... Thank you so much , i will check

Answer (score 2):

When saving a file in c#, if no directory is specified, the application writes to the running directory, which is normally where the application is.

Comment: And you can change the CWD via [Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: It can also be changed if the application is launched via console or via a shortcut